# What is the best way to check a given variable is NaN or not?

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to check a given variable is NaN or not?

(only using pure Javascript without any libraries such as Underscore)

Comment: [**isNaN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) must be considered as the best way.

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript has function `isNaN` for that purpose. As described in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp):

> The isNaN() function determines whether a value is an illegal number
>   (Not-a-Number).
>
> This function returns true if the value is NaN, and false if not.

For example:

```
isNaN(123) // returns false;
isNaN("Hello")  //returns true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isNaN(x)` which returns a boolean value (true if x is NaN, false otherwise).